# Which of these two sentences is correct?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

Which of the following sentences is correct?

> I have a tremendous amount of respect in you.

> I have a tremendous amount of respect for you.

Comment: Welcome to ELL.SE. I strongly encourage you to take the site [tour] and review the [help] for a better understanding of Stack Exchange and how it works.

Answer (score 4):

The noun "respect" takes "for" for its indirect object, not "in".

(This is nothing to do with meanings: it is just an accidental fact about the English noun "respect", that has to be learnt along with its spelling and pronunciation).

So "respect for you".

Evidence: The iWeb corpus contains 127 697 instances of "respect for", against 7 011 of "respect in". Looking through the first page of examples of "respect in", I didn't see a single one where "in" introduced the object of the respect.

Comment: May it be the other way around? I have a tremendous amount of respect in you = You respect me deeply.

Comment: The verb would not be **have**, @Mv Log.  *You may have in him a great friend* but you do not have great respect in him.  *What* you have must be of the same ilk or kind (or at least something which can be compared to it) as the object of the preposition **in** in that construction.

Comment: You could say  *I have a great helper in you* or *I have a great worker in you* or  *I have a great beast of burden in you* or *I have a great I-do-not-know-what in you.*  But you cannot say *I have a great concern in you*.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo  But what about **have it in you**? _I don't think she has it in her to be cruel._

Comment: @Mv Log: That's an entirely different construction.  *Do you have it in you?* means "Do you have the fortitude | energy | gumption | chutzpah | whatever {to do something}?"

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo I don't think these are so much different, **respect** seems to be of the same kind. I agree that it may sound unidiomatic but why not say for example _Have you got any respect in you for her feelings?_ or even better _Why haven't you got any respect in you for her feelings?_

Comment: @Mv Log: The statement *You respect me deeply* is simply not expressed by "I have a tremendous amount of respect in you", regardless of what you may think.  It does not mean what you think it might mean, and your examples are off-point.

Comment: @MvLog "There is no kindness or respect in me." I agree with you that *this* is okay. However, the specific context is different than in the question here. Somebody may be said to have respect "in" themselves (which they could "give" to somebody else), but they can't have respect "in" somebody else.

Comment: @Jason Bassford _I am very much surprised to find such respect for my family in you._ Is that incorrect?

Comment: @Mv Log: *I have much respect for my family in you* is gibberish, no matter that you are surprised to find that respect for them in me.

Comment: @MvLog I find nothing wrong with that phrasing. (I disagree that it's gibberish. It remains unusual but it's still perfectly understandable.) However, it's *not* the same thing as the incorrect "I have respect in your family." What you just said is *I have respect* ***for*** *your family in me.*

Comment: @MvLog that should be it's own question. But I would find all of those sentences VERY weird, and would not understand them without further clarification (as an AmE native speaker)

Comment: Why mix up two different things? And why don't all you people who want to discuss respect for x in y, put up a different answer. Basically, Colin's answer covers the OP's question. The rest is extra.